# Flutter: how to dynamically create a horizontal timeline widget

Tags: flutter

I am creating  4 pages (forms)in flutter that has next and prev button on the bottom of the form . Then depending on the active page, I would like to show the user the image attached on the top of each page

The image show that user is on page 3 and prev 2 pages are completed

How can I create this. ?

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, there's no readymade package to do this. You'll have to write your own class to achieve and it is fairly easy. Sample code below and full code [here](https://pastebin.com/rzXPz9wS).

Just call the class below as ScreenProgress(ticks:2) and it'll return something similar to the image in your question.

Note : Use the code below as a sample (and not a final implementation).

```
class ScreenProgress extends StatelessWidget {

  final int ticks;

  ScreenProgress({@required this.ticks});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        tick1(),
        spacer(),
        line(),
        spacer(),
        tick2(),
        spacer(),
        line(),
        spacer(),
        tick3(),
        spacer(),
        line(),
        spacer(),
        tick4(),
      ],
    );


  }

  Widget tick(bool isChecked){
    return isChecked?Icon(Icons.check_circle,color: Colors.blue,):Icon(Icons.radio_button_unchecked, color: Colors.blue,);
  }

  Widget tick1() {
    return this.ticks>0?tick(true):tick(false);
  }
  Widget tick2() {
    return this.ticks>1?tick(true):tick(false);
  }
  Widget tick3() {
    return this.ticks>2?tick(true):tick(false);
  }
  Widget tick4() {
    return this.ticks>3?tick(true):tick(false);
  }

  Widget spacer() {
    return Container(
      width: 5.0,
    );
  }

  Widget line() {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 5.0,
      width: 50.0,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are some packages at pub.dev for what you want, you can try those 2 packages :

1. https://pub.dev/packages/timelines
2. https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_tile

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32275939)